# Why I am not able to commit any repository in github?

Tags: github, commit, readme

I have many private repositories on my GitHub. Until yesterday I was able to commit to any repository on my GitHub. But today, I am trying to change the readme.md file in my repository, I am not able to see the preview and also not able to commit as the commit button is disabled.

Actually, later I saw that I am unable to commit any file in chrome browser only , but I can commit any file in other browser (Microsoft Edge) . And also, I am able to commit from my IDE (MS Visual Studio) . So, My question is that , why I am unable to commit from Chrome only.

[image: Screenshot of Github commit button disabled]

Comment: Is this relevant?  https://superuser.com/questions/277618/github-not-accessible-from-google-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this problem:
Problem is occurring  due to I Added extension in chrome i.e. ad blocker extension.
So, I removed that extension and problem is solved.

Comment: For me, it was Ghostery that disable commit changes button... Thats weird

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have modified/updated any contents in the README.md file. If there is no changes in the file, "Commit Changes" but will be disabled.

[image]

Comment: Actually, later I saw that I am unable to commit any file in chrome browser only , but I can commit any file in other browser (Microsoft Edge) . And also, I am able to commit from my IDE (MS Visual Studio) . So, My question is that , why I am unable to commit from Chrome only.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I deactivated/trusted Ghostery for uniquely github.com

Image shows active Ghostery:
[image: Image shows active Ghostery]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found by adding the file name you are going to create in the url can solve the issue.
yourusername/new-file-name.html. (in main)